# Vectors: The point 2/3 of the way along AC from A?

Tags: vectors

Let $\vec{OA} = \mathbf a$ and $\vec{OB} = \mathbf b.$

The question is: What is the position vector of the point $\frac23$ of the way along $\vec{AC}$ from $A?$

I don't understand the solution given in my book. Shouldn't it be $\frac23(\vec{AO}+\frac12\vec{OB}) = \frac13 \mathbf b - \frac23 \mathbf a ?$

[image: Solution]][image: Triangle]

Answer (score 2):

Let the intersection of $AC$ and $OE$ be $X.$

- Your suggested answer is the expression for $\vec{AX}.$
- On the other hand, the given answer is the expression for $\vec{OX}.$

The “position vector of $X$” refers to $\vec{OX},$ not $\vec{AX}.$

Comment: I think I have my answer: "Yes, almost! You calculated the translation vector 2/3 AC = 1/3 b - 2/3 a. But we want the position vector of a point, when you start at A and then walk along your translation vector. Therefore, OA + 2/3 AC. "

Comment: @MariuszGarniewski Yes but you're complicating it: my point was that the "position vector" of a point is a standard phrase that has a particular meaning: it is defined as the displacement vector of that point with respect to the origin.   When the exercise asks for the [position vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_(geometry)) of $G,$ they are simply asking for $\vec{OG},$ which is the direct vector from $O$ to $G.$  Sure, $\vec{OG}$ happens to equal $\vec{OK}+\vec{KY}+\vec{YG},$ and that's because there are multiple equivalent paths to move from $O$ to $G.$

Comment: It's true that the desired solution is plain and simply a simplified expression for $\vec{OX}$. However, note that even in the "book" the first step of the solution writes $\frac23\vec{AC}$ as $\frac23(\frac12 \mathbf b - \mathbf a)$, which they simplify to $\frac13 \mathbf b - \frac23\mathbf a$ in the next step, so OP's mistake (relative to the "book" solution) really is just forgetting that this quantity has to be added to $\vec{OA}$. (And after that addition, of course, simplify to a linear combination of $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b.$)

Answer (score 0):

No, its fine: $ 0C = 1/2 * 0B$, i.e. $c = 1/2*b$.